# Close web page after sending headers (php)

Tags: php, javascript, phpexcel

I am currently finishing a web page in php.

Basically there is some data on it that needs to be outputed to an Excel file.
So after googleing a bit a found this [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) project, and outputed the data using that. That works perfect.

Now, when the said data output accurs i use the `window.open(URL_OF_THE_MAKEOUTPUT.PHP_FILE_GOES_HERE)` javascript function so the current window that hold the data is intact. Now, i would like to close that second window when the excel file is generated and started to download to the clients computer.

So, up until now I know i have a problem with this little piece of code

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=report-'.date('d.m.Y').'.xls');
```

Becouse of it, I cannot do this afterwerds ->

```
echo "<script>window.close;</script>";
```

I tried using

```
ob_start("callback");
```

at thery beginng of the page, and

```
ob_end_flush();
```

at the end, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Tnx in advance!!!

Comment: Yes, you cannot send raw HTML in an Excel output stream. HTTP requests can only have one content type. It's not quite clear why you open a second window in the first place. The original content doesn't go away if you send those headers. It should popup a download dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd probably want to do is use this instead:

```
location.href = URL_OF_THE_MAKEOUTPUT.PHP_FILE_GOES_HERE;
```

It will redirect to the download script and since it's a file attachment, it will not leave the current page but instead show a Download File dialog from your browser.

Comment: yeah... that makes a lot of snese... i'll accept this in 3 mins :) tnx!

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `window.open` to open a popup window. If you call your URL in the main window and it is a download (which it is, thanks to your `header()` calls), your browser will be smart and leave the existing page/data in the window intact. So, there's no need for a popup.

Comment: Yes.  Also, you can't mix document types like this; once you've told the browser to expect an Excel document, it won't interpret any HTML or JavaScript because it doesn't expect to see any.